# 'Unattended upgrades' does not reboot system

Tags: 12.04, apt, unattended-upgrades

I have set up 'unattended upgrades' on a 12.04 LTS machine. It's working quite fine with the exception of that it doesn't reboot even  though all config files have been set to enable this.

Config files under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d:

50unattended-upgrades http://pastebin.com/850NqExv
10periodic http://pastebin.com/t0Xh9PPx

```
/var/run/reboot-required exists and has the contents "\*\*\* System restart required \*\*\*"
```

Actually now that I'm thinking of it unattended upgrades is having some problems sending email to the recipient due to network/mail issues. This is the only (albeit remote) source of trouble I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I be damned, it proved to be the mailing issue all along. Once we sorted out the email problems 'unattended upgrades' rebooted the system just as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the `/var/run/reboot-required` is only set whenever the kernel (I think libc too) is updated, the services are restarted when upgrading, and since GNU/Linux is a modular OS, you won't need to restart for almost anything, but kernel.

If your system don't reboot, it may be due no new kernels available. If you are not sure, you can check `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` and `unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log`. apt also have some hooks that trigger this, just didn't found the documentation.